# Problema com array no Java

Tags: java, array, nullpointerexception

Estou tentando criar uma agenda de contatos em java, estou usando algumas classes que foram pedidas no exercício.

a classe principal:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Lista15Q03 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int max = 3;

        Endereco end[] = new Endereco[max];

        Telefones tel[] = new Telefones[max];

        Emails email[] = new Emails[max];

        Contatos con[] = new Contatos[max];
        Contatos c = new Contatos();
        c.setEndereco(end);

        int op;
        int indice = 0;

        do {

            System.out.println("1 - adicionar");
            System.out.println("2 - listar");
            System.out.println("3 - mostrar");
            System.out.println("4 - alterar");
            System.out.println("5 - apagar");
            System.out.println("6 - sair");
            System.out.print("escolha: ");
            op = scan.nextInt();

            switch(op){
                case 1:
                    if(indice < max){

                        c = new Contatos();

                        System.out.println("nome: ");
                        String nome = scan.next();
                        c.setNome(nome);

                        System.out.print("nome da rua: ");
                        String rua = scan.next();
                        end[indice].setRua(rua);

                        System.out.print("número: ");
                        String num = scan.next();
                        end[indice].setNumero(num);

                        System.out.print("bairro: ");
                        String bairro = scan.next();
                        end[indice].setRua(bairro);

                        con[indice] = c;
                        indice++;
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("");
                        System.out.println("lista de contatos cheia");
                        System.out.println("");
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    break;
                case 6:
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("opção inválida");
            }

        } while (op != 6);

    }

}
```

a classe de contatos:

```
public class Contatos {
    private String nome;
    private Endereco[] endereco;
    private Emails[] email;
    private Telefones[] telefones;

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public Endereco[] getEndereco(){
        return endereco;
    }

    public void setEndereco(Endereco[] endereco){
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }

    public Emails[] getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(Emails[] email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Telefones[] getTelefones() {
        return telefones;
    }

    public void setTelefones(Telefones[] telefones) {
        this.telefones = telefones;
    }

}
```

erro executando no terminal:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at Lista15Q03.main(Lista15Q03.java:46)

erro executando no netbeans:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at lista15q03.Lista15Q03.main(Lista15Q03.java:41)
/home/henrique/.cache/netbeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
FALHA NA CONSTRUÇÃO (tempo total: 5 segundos)
```

Comment: Onde é a linha 46?

Comment: Posta o stack trace completo.

Comment: Poderia detalhar mais o projeto e aonde ocorre o problema?

Comment: a linha 46 é essa: end[indice].setRua(rua);

Comment: Os dois erros ocorrem em linhas diferentes, um diz linha 41 e outro 43

Comment: Tenho que criar uma agenda com funcionalidades crud, então criei 4 classes, Email, Telefones, Endereco e Contatos. Eu referencio a outras classes na classe contatos como array. Na classe principal do programa, eu instancio a classe Contatos e também jogo ela dentro do array.

Comment: Isso é por que no netbeans tem a linha do package e no sublime não. Então o erro é realmente a partir desse trecho: end[indice].setRua(rua);

Comment: Esse indice do vetor  não foi inicializado, vc apenas inicializou ele como array, mas não individualmente

Comment: Você criou um vetor de endereços mas o vetor não possui nenhum objeto do tipo endereço. Logo você está acessando um vetor vazio. Por isso ocorre o nullpointer.

Comment: então no caso eu tenho que instanciar Endereco e jogar o objeto dentro c.setEndereco(); ?

Answer (score 1):

Faltou vc instanciar os objetos nas posições dos arrays `end[]`, `tel[]`, `email`.

Nas chamadas

> ```
> Endereco end[] = new Endereco[max];
>
> Telefones tel[] = new Telefones[max];
>
> Emails email[] = new Emails[max];
> ```

Apenas foram instanciados os array de cada um desses objetos com operador `new`.

Para cada array vc precisa um for que percorre todo o array instanciando os objetos

Como no exemplo abaixo

```
  for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            end[i] = new Endereco();
        }
```

No entanto, noto que os objetos **Endereco**, **Emails**, e **Telefones** já são atributos da classe **Contatos**. Deste modo, uma maneira mais correta seria removê-los da classe main e adicionar um método para a inicialização destes objetos em suas próprias classes. Como no exemplo abaixo.

```
public class Contatos {

    int max;
    private String nome;
    private Endereco[] endereco;
    private Emails[] email;
    private Telefones[] telefones;

    public Contatos(int max) {
        this.max = max;
        initEnderecos();
   }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
   }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
   }

    public Endereco[] getEndereco() {
       return endereco;
   }

    public void setEndereco(Endereco[] endereco) {
        this.endereco = endereco;
  }

    public Emails[] getEmail() {
        return email;
  }

    public void setEmail(Emails[] email) {
       this.email = email;
  } 

    public Telefones[] getTelefones() {
       return telefones;
  }

   public void setTelefones(Telefones[] telefones) {
      this.telefones = telefones;
  }

   private void initEnderecos() {
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            this.endereco[i] = new Endereco();
        }
   }
}
```

Neste exemplo eu movi o atributo `max`, que é o tamanho máximo da lista de contatos para a classe `Contato` e inicializo apenas o `array` de `Endereco`. Os outros vc pode fazer de forma análoga.

Note que, esta é apenas **uma** das melhorias que vc pode fazer neste código

Comment: vou tentar implementar isso, já já posto resultado, mas desde já agradeço.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Irei deu certo com a resposta do parceiro ali em cima, vou tentar implementar essas dicas depois. vlw.

Comment: Beleza, a resposta que publiquei foi apenas para a resolução deste problema. Identifiquei alguns outros problemas no código, no entanto resolvi apenas o problema relacionado a dúvida.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, o problema que está acontecendo é que foi apenas declaro o valor para array como new Endereco, contudo cada item dela fica null até ser inicializada, então terá que fazer essa inicialização antes de aderir valores as variáveis desse objeto.

```
 switch(op){
             case 1:
                 if(indice < max){

                     end[indice] = new Endereco();
                     c = new Contato();

                     System.out.println("nome: ");
                     String nome = scan.next();
                     c.setNome(nome);

                     System.out.print("nome da rua: ");
                     String rua = scan.next();
                     end[indice].setRua(rua);

                     System.out.print("número: ");
                     String num = scan.next();
                     end[indice].setNumero(num);

                     System.out.print("bairro: ");
                     String bairro = scan.next();
                     end[indice].setBairro(bairro);

                     c.setEndereco(end);
                     con[indice] = c;
                     indice++;
                 }
```

Uma outra coisa que percebi analisando seu codigo é que seta um endereço no objeto c, contudo dps inicializa-o novamente, perdendo o que foi setado que no caso não tinha nada, o mais correto a se fazer é apenas colocar esse valor depois de inserir todos os itens do endereço, e tbm estava colocando o valor do bairro na rua.

Comment: kk Valeu, nem tinha reparado nessa parte do valor do bairro na rua. Resolução muito simples, muito obrigado fera. :) acho que lembro de você de uma outra dúvida anterior de Java tbm kk vlw \o/

Comment: kkkkkk, Normalmente os erros que dão são bem simples, o ruim é encontrar.

Answer (score 1):

Se puder usar `List`, faça que vai ser mais feliz, se não puder, tera que criar um objeto para cada Array que você criou, pois cada posição do Array está esperando um objeto  e você está passando uma String. então no seu caso ficaria assim.

obs: vou fazer apenas com um dos Array e vocÊ replica.

```
Endereco []end = new Endereco[max]; // cada posição tem que ser um objeto
Endereco endereco = new Endereco();

System.out.print("nome da rua: ");
String rua = scan.next();
endereco.setRua(rua);
end[indice] = endereco;

end[indice].getRua(); //para mostrar o valor depois.
```